# TreeViewItem.ParentTreeViewItem is internal but is there a way to get it?

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchy, treeviewitem

I'm trying to write code that can accept `Key.Down` and `Key.Up` and change the selection of a `TreeView` that is using several `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s.  In the children of a `TreeViewItem`, I need to get its parent so that I can determine what the next node should be selected.  I noticed that `TreeViewItem` has a `ParentTreeViewItem` property, but its set to internal and therefore not exposed to access.  Is there another way to emulate how to get the parent of a `TreeViewItem` as a `TreeViewItem`?  Note: `Parent` is always null when using `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: TreeView already accepts key up and down by default. Key right expands the selected node. However, you must traverse the tree using the data structure and not the containers. Your data models must have a reference to their parent if the parent is of interest. Even without such a parent reference you can start from the root and then find the current item by temporarily storing the parent before stepping in to the next level.  If you have found the current item, you also have the parent from the previous step.

Comment: I believe that when HeirarchicalDataTemplates are used, that the up/down keys no longer work.  See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2a2f6ce-24f2-495a-8515-0382cd903066/how-to-move-selection-by-updown-key-press-in-treeview-control-in-wpf-and-use-mouse-to-click?forum=wpf

Comment: @BionicCode I created a class 'MultiSelectTreeView' that inherits 'TreeView'.  I was trying to write this in a generic way so that it could be used in other data structures. That's why I want the parent as a TreeViewItem instead of its underlying data.

Comment: Up and down keys will work. This is not church: don't believe, test the facts and know. To get the parent element, you can always use the VisualTreeHelper.GetParent helper.

Comment: @BionicCode  I do know they don't work, I meant that because of the HeirarchicalDataTemplates, they don't.  VisualTreeHelper.GetParent won't work because the parent of the TreeViewItem is a VirtualizingStackPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` to find any parent element:

```
private bool TryGetVisualParent<TParent>(DependencyObject element, out TParent parent) where TParent : DependencyObject
{
  parent = null;

  if (element is null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
  if (element is TParent parentElement)
  {
    parent = parentElement;
    return true;
  }

  return TryGetVisualParent(element, out parent);
}
```

**Usage Example**

```cs
private void OnTreeViewItem_Selcted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var selectedItem = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
  if (TryGetVisualParent(selectedItem, out TreeViewItem parentItem))
  {
    // Handle 'parentItem'
  }
}
```

Comment: That solved it.  Thanks.  I love how people down vote my question, then someone returns a reasonable answer.  What a world...

Answer (score 1):

Use TreeViewItem.Parent Property,If the parent property is null, it means there is no parent node

```
 <TreeView>
      <TreeViewItem Header="root">
            <TreeViewItem Header="child" Name="child_item"></TreeViewItem>
      </TreeViewItem>
 </TreeView>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not work if the items are generated via data templates.

Comment: @sync You can plainly see in my image that ParentTreeViewItem has what I want and Parent is null.

Comment: I just saw that, in theory, the tree is a hierarchical structure, and the parent node is not empty.